# Is there an option to "force" the dash to open a file after I click on it instead of going to options?

Tags: unity-dash, scopes

When I launch an application from the dash I just need to type a few letters and when I see the application I want, I just click on it and it opens.

The problem in the Files & Folder lens. When I see a file in the list, I need to click on it and then it will go down one level and give a few options (Open, Show in Folder and Email) and then I can open it.

Is there an option where I could skip this one level so this file would act as an application?

Comment: I think you're talking about the Dash rather than the HUD. A good question anyway!

Answer (score 0):

In 14.04, if you double-click the file in the Files & Folders lens then it seems to open straight away (using the default application), without going through the drop-down.  Does that help?